# Vaults not recognized after system update

Tags: fallout-shelter

I made an Android System Update of my device and now none of my vaults are recognized by the game anymore. The save files (vault1.sav and vault2.sav) are still available in

```
/storage/sdcard1/0/Android/data/com.bethsoft.falloutshelter/files
```

However, the game does not want to load any of them.

Is there any way to force the game to load them? I bet not, but maybe someone else has some solution...

Comment: Try to delete the app (save the game files first!), reinstall it from the appstore on your phone, put the save files into the installation and move it to the SD Card after wards. This helped in my case.

Comment: done, glad that i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the app (save the game files first!), reinstall it from the appstore on your phone, put the save files into the installation and move it to the SD Card after wards. The game will recognize the save files then.